# Format items in a list automatically

Tags: python, list, format

How would I correctly format a list of items without having to manually do it?

```
xy_coords = [(15, 5),
(9, 0),
(3, 5),
(13, 7),
(21, 1),
(19, 22),
(22, 2),
(11, 11),
(10, 21),
(24, 2),
(19, 19)]
```

Comment: This is not a proper list. Tell us what you want to achieve, if possible give us an example.

Comment: Do you want to store some tuples in a list? There should be comma between every coordinate as: [(15,5),(9,0),(3,5)].

Comment: @Vishwas That's what i already asked.

Comment: I want to take this improper list xy_coords = [(15, 5) (9, 0) (3, 5) (13, 7) (21, 1) (19, 22) (22, 2) (11, 11) (10, 21) (24, 2) (19, 19)]   and change it to a proper list xy_coords = [(15, 5),  (9, 0),  (3, 5),  (13, 7),  (21, 1) , (19, 22), (22, 2), (11, 11) , (10, 21),  (24, 2),  (19, 19)] so I can use it. But I was wondering how I could do that without having to manually go through and add commas to seperate the items.

Comment: @CodeIt sorry, should of just put that in the first place.

Comment: @RLD_1999 Is that a string ?

Comment: @CodeIt they are tuples in a list.

Comment: @RLD_1999 The list values must be separated by commas. If you could post the associated code when produces this **strange list** do share with us.

Comment: @CodeIt How would I do that without doing it manually? Could I use a for loop to add commas for me? Because the actual list of tuples is pretty large and could take awhile.

Comment: If it is a list then it will contain tuples separated by commas. Otherwise it is not a proper list or it is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `xy_coords` is a string, I would have used a [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to find all occurrences of couples (x, y) and then convert the strings into integers.

This can be done with the [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-contents) function. The RegEx can be minimal and only match the two coordinates. By using groups in your RegEx, the function will return a list of string tuples that you need to convert into `int`.

For instance:

```py
import re

xy_coords = '[(15, 5) (9, 0) (3, 5) (13, 7) (21, 1) (19, 22) (22, 2) (11, 11) (10, 21) (24, 2) (19, 19)]'

xy_coords = [
    tuple(map(int, coord))
    for coord in re.findall(r"(\d+),\s*(\d+)", xy_coords)
]
print(xy_coords)
```

The result is a list of int tuples:

```py
[(15, 5), (9, 0), (3, 5), (13, 7), (21, 1), (19, 22), (22, 2), (11, 11), (10, 21), (24, 2), (19, 19)]
```

Comment: Sure will. If you don't mind could you explain  what the for loop is basically doing, so I have a better understanding? :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the variable `xy_coords` is not a list. You will get an error if you run that line. 
Ignoring that, and assuming `xy_coords` is a `String`, it will look like this:

```
xy_coords = '[(15, 5) (9, 0) (3, 5) (13, 7) (21, 1) (19, 22) (22, 2) (11, 11) (10, 21) (24, 2) (19, 19)]'
```

(note the single quotes above, which makes `xy_coords` a string)

Now, to add the commas between each tuple, you can do this:

```
new = ''
a = string.split(') ')
for k in a[:-1]:
    new+=(k+'), ')
new+=a[-1]
print(new)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[(15, 5), (9, 0), (3, 5), (13, 7), (21, 1), (19, 22), (22, 2), (11, 11), (10, 21), (24, 2), (19, 19)]
```

Comment: The OP has mentioned that it is not a string. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963113/format-items-in-a-list-automatically#comment100463907_56963113)

Comment: Apologies, but I have mentioned that the OP was clearly wrong in saying that the variable is a list of tuples. I just did what OP wanted, even though OP did not know what kind of variable it is :)

Comment: I think our assumption is correct, the OP is yet to respond.